# Jquery Ajax POST being appended to url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I fixed one thing in my code that broke my ajax submit. Not sure what's going wrong here. The PHP has been unchanged since everything was working. For some reason, and I'm unsure if this is supposed to happen or not, the datastring is appended to the url. The alert box never appears.

```
$('#contact_submit').click(function(e){
    var datastring = 'name='+ $('#name').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&inquiry='+ $('#inquiry_dropdown option:selected').text() + '&message='+ $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "process-contact.php",  
        data: datastring,  
        success: function(data) {  
            alert(data);
        }  
    });
    alert ("We've received your request and will alert you once the directory is available. Thank you.");
    $('#submit_form_contact').reset();
});  
//    if ($("#submit_form_contact").valid()) {
//    }
});
```

Comment: After fixing your formatting, it looks like you have an extra `});` in your code. If that's in your real code, it will cause the JavaScript to fail. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Also, in future, keep your code indented properly. It means you can spot errors like this instantly.

Comment: Add a fail callback as well to see if something is breaking on the server.

Comment: Finally, the form data being appended to the URL is the default form behaviour (assuming it wasn't set to `method=post`), which happens if your callback doesn't `preventDefault` on the event (I don't see that in your code, but you say it worked before so I assume it may be hidden away in there somewhere), or if your code hits an error before calling `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear you are sending a datastring that will append in url, instead of send it  like

```
var datastring = 'name='+ $('#name').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&inquiry='+ $('#inquiry_dropdown option:selected').text() + '&message='+ $('#message').val();
```

send it like

```
var datastring = {"name" : $('#name').val(),
                  "email": $('#email').val() 
                    .......
                     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Jquery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method instead of building the data manually